# запросы к mysql в php7

Tags: php7

При переходе на php 7, столкнулся с невозможностью подключения к бд mysql привычным способом:
PHP код:

```
mysql_connect($server, $user, $pswd) or die ('Нет связи с Базой Данных'); 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ('Ведутся технические работы!');
```

В Справочниках говорят, что используется pdo или функция mysqli. Подключиться, с помощью второй удалось:
PHP код:

```
mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pswd, $db)or die ('Нет связи с Базой Данных');
```

, но как делать запросы на инфу из базы? Интерпретатор постоянно пишет:
PHP код:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in ... 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in...
```

Что за второй параметр? Помогите, как лучше делать?

Comment: Давай по порядку Коннектится к базе? Установлен на apache сервере mysqlnd модуль для работы с mysqli?  перезагружал апач после настрое сервак перезагружал? 

вот так попробуй с делать 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT 'Мир, полный ' AS _msg FROM DUAL");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['_msg'];

Comment: Первым параметром передаю результат подключения к бд.

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pswd, $db); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit(); } - это в конфиге

Comment: Выдает мир полный

Comment: в каком конфиге?

Comment: это файл config.php

Comment: $mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pswd, $db);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
  {
   echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } 
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT one FROM table WHERE one=one");
  $iss = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  echo $iss['one']; - сейчас вот так на прямую пробую, по вашему шаблону

Comment: выдает следующее: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); сделай

Answer (score 1):

Нужно везде во всех запросах поставить mysqli

```
<?php
// Подключаешься к базе
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname")or die ('Нет связи с Базой Данных');

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `tablename`");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
```

Везде где видешь mysql поменяй на mysqli

Comment: Вы не внимательно прочитали

Comment: И все равно, Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in...

Comment: Первым параметром передаешь $connect или как у Вас $db?

Comment: Первым параметром передаю результат подключения к бд.

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pswd, $db);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}  - это в конфиге

Comment: require_once 'inc/conf.php';
 connect();
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT someone FROM stuff WHERE someone=one");
  $iss = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  echo $iss['someone']; - а это код, который ошибку вызывает

Comment: попробуй исправить на: WHERE someone='one'

Comment: И что такое connect()

Comment: connect(); - это функция

Comment: база есть права на использования базы у юзера есть? перезагружал апач и mysql сервера?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = "вставь сюда бешеный зарос аля SELECT * FROM твоя таблица";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

/* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}

/* удаление выборки */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* закрытие соединения */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: $iss = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo $iss['url']; - так?  Если да, то ошибка не изменилась!

Comment: сделай var_dump($iss) данные есть?

Comment: null пишет.....

Comment: база пустая а ты получить от нее хочешь что то )))

Comment: она не может быть пустой! В ней 2 записи, к одной из них я обращаюсь. Все работало, пока я не обновил php до 7 версии. mysqli - это же аналог mysql? Я правильно понимаю? Или это sqlite?

Comment: сервера перезагружал или нет ? через phpMyadmin можешь посмотреть есть там что у тебя в базе или нет?

Comment: Сервер перезагрузил, сейчас еще раз попробую. В базу захожу свободно... Уже подставлял и другие таблицы, все равно ничего. Попробую еще раз резетнуть

Comment: СЕРВЕРА MySQL тожэ перестартани.

Comment: нет, ничего не изменилось

Comment: а как аналогичный запрос сделать на PDO?

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь! Проблема была в моих кривых руках) Я объявлял переменные с инфой для подключения через функцию, вместо тог, чтобы указать их явно